# Alpaca Large Language Model from Python script

Tags: python, c#, artificial-intelligence, gpt-3, large-language-model

I was able to install [Alpaca](https://github.com/antimatter15/alpaca.cpp)  under Linux and start and use it interactivelly via the corresponding `./chat` command.

However, I would like to run it not in interactive mode but from a Python (Jupyter) script with the prompt as string parameter. Also, it should be possible to call the model several times without needing to reload it each time.

I already wrote a Python script that works technically:

```
import subprocess

# start the Alpaca model as a subprocess 
alpaca_process = subprocess.Popen(["./chat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

# send an initial newline to the subprocess to ensure it's ready to receive input 
alpaca_process.stdin.write("\n") 
alpaca_process.stdin.flush()

def alpaca_predict(prompt):
    # send the prompt to Alpaca and get the output
    alpaca_process.stdin.write(prompt + "\n")
    alpaca_process.stdin.flush()
    output = alpaca_process.stdout.readline().strip()
    return output

# test the function 
prompts = ["Hello", "What is the meaning of life?", "Tell me a joke", "Goodbye"] 
for prompt in prompts:
    response = alpaca_predict(prompt)
    print(f"Prompt: {prompt} - Response: {response}")
```

It works technically now, but unfortunately the model produces only nonsense like this:

```
Prompt: Hello - Response: 
Prompt: What is the meaning of life? - Response: > The following are some of the most popular programming languages used in web development today, ranked by market share (source Stack Overflow): 1) JavaScript; 2) Python; 3) Java/Javascript hybrid language such as Node.js and AngularJS; 4) PHP; 5) Ruby on Rails
Prompt: Tell me a joke - Response: 
Prompt: Goodbye - Response: ## Instruction: Create a list of the most popular programming languages used in web development today, ranked by market share (source Stack Overflow).
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your passing the prompt in a particular manner.`prompt_1 = "### Instruction: write the product description based on attributes=[Fit-Type : Slim Fit, color : Blue, Neck : Round Neck, Pattern : Printed ,Sleeve Styling : Regular Sleeves, Material: Pure Cotton].don't include other text\n\n### Response: "`

Comment: Does not work for the given program, unfortunately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your original \n:
alpaca_process.stdin.write("\n")
it is causing alpaca to think that you want a response to nothing basically.
If you comment that out it seems to work